# git push heroku master rejected

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, heroku

I want to deploy my first springboot app with mysql to heroku (using git and heroku cli), but failed when running git push heroku master rejected.

```
remote:        [INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
remote:        [INFO] Compiling 7 source files to /tmp/build_c5e0f2b5/target/classes
remote:        [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
remote:        [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
remote:        [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
remote:        [INFO] Total time:  8.934 s
remote:        [INFO] Finished at: 2022-07-27T16:58:41Z
remote:        [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
remote:        [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1:compile (default-compile) on project MyWebApp: Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 18 -> [Help 1]
remote:        [ERROR]
remote:        [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
remote:        [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
remote:        [ERROR]
remote:        [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
remote:        [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
remote:
remote:  !     ERROR: Failed to build app with Maven
remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! If you can't find the issue in application code,
remote:        please submit a ticket so we can help: https://help.heroku.com/
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Java app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote:  !
remote:  ! ## Warning - The same version of this code has already been built: ff84352b22a5ff214782161029fd4ff8ec067734
remote:  !
remote:  ! We have detected that you have triggered a build from source code with version ff84352b22a5ff214782161029fd4ff8ec067734
remote:  ! at least twice. One common cause of this behavior is attempting to deploy code from a different branch.
remote:  !
remote:  ! If you are developing on a branch and deploying via git you must run:
remote:  !
remote:  !     git push heroku <branchname>:main
remote:  !
remote:  ! This article goes into details on the behavior:
remote:  !   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/duplicate-build-version
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to aien-app-1.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/aien-app-1.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/aien-app-1.git'
```

Does anyone know how to solve it?I beg for help

Comment: This has nothing to do with *Git*, which in this case is just relaying error messages from Heroku. The important error (as relayed by Git, hence with `remote:` in front) seems to be `Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 18`. This seems like a java version selection error.

Comment: @torek thanks for your information, so do you know what should I do for that error?

Comment: I don't do Java programming in general, so no, but I imagine it's really easy to search.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your code does not compile for some reason. That may be due to the git branch you are on. Have you tried the suggested:

`git push heroku <branchname>:main`

Comment: sorry, which <branchname> is referring to? I'm totally new to this

Answer (score 0):

It appears you're pushing to the wrong branch since Heroku now deploys from the main branch by default. First run

```bash
git branch
```

to see what branch you're on. For example, if it shows an asterisk next to master, then run

```bash
git push heroku master:main
```

or if it says main,

```bash
git push heroku main:main # or "git push heroku main"
```

More information can be seen at the link in your command's output ([here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/duplicate-build-version))